# UIGestureRecognizer rendered off screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got a `UIGestureRecognizer` that is attached to a `UILabel` that is rendered off screen, when brought into view later. After its brought into view, the tap gesture recognizer does not work. If rendered in the view, it works fine.

Any ideas why this would not work? And how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the recognizer after the label is brought into the view?

Comment: Is there any other (transparent) view overlaying/overlapping the label after it is brought into the view?

Comment: I resolved this by subclassing UILabel and implementing the hitTest:withEvent:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing `UILabel` and implementing `hitTest:withEvent:` resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that its related to "rendering" it off screen (and what do you mean by that). In any case, I suggest when the label is brought onto the screen that you verify that the label is enabled, then do something like this:

```
NSArray *grs = label.gestureRecognizers; 
for(UIGestureRecognizer *gr in grs) {
  NSLog(@"Recognizer: %@ enabled=%d state=%d del=%@", NSStringFromClass[gr class]), gr.enabled, gr.state, gr.delegate);
}
```

It would be interesting to compare results from the offscreen versus the onscreen. Something is going on and just need to find out what property is different. No way to get the list of target/action pairs though.